# Does the voters tab show everyone who's voted?

Tags: discussion, support, voting

Or does it show only those who have cast, say, 5 votes?  If it's everyone, it seems like 14 people voting so far this week is very very low.

[image]

Comment: I believe it only shows people who voted 11 or more times.

Comment: I know I have cast a couple today.  Not sure how often those stats are calculated.  It doesn't appear to be real-time.

Answer (score 2):

It's been the Easter weekend. A lot of people won't have been on the site. Especially if they live in a country that gives you a public holiday on Monday. In Australia we had a public holiday on Monday and Tuesday (co-incidence), so some of us have been away for even longer ;)

Comment: This was also reflected in the lower than normal number of questions and answers posted over the weekend.

Comment: According to the analytics, traffic dropped substantially more than usual this easter weekend

Comment: we're looking into that, you can ping Kyle or George for more detail. Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/51136/remove-nofollow-on-links-at-a-certain-age